# Get threads are held for locking a mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, pthreads

I just wondered how would I get(count) the threads are held for locking a mutex, for example considering the following example

```
void _foo(void* arg){
pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);//[ABC]
//doing something
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);
}
```

so the question: how would I find out how many threads are currently waiting to get lock the `_lock` at `[ABC]` in pthread? or any other parallel lib.

and a little more confusing question, is it possible to redirect the waiting threads to somewhere else? for example just after the first thread process, waiting threads will be redirected to `_bar()` method, I mean change the code execution at runtime.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do those things? There's probably a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @AlanStokes an object should be deleted just by first thread call, so the very next thread which is waiting will get error. so what is your suggestion dear?

Comment: I'm suggesting you explain why you want to do these things.

Comment: consider the `_foo()` method belongs to `A` class, at a time 10 threads call the `_foo()`. this method does a thread-safe operation, then have to delete the current object `this`, so if the first thread delete the object, other waiting threads will be gotten an error. so I want to delete an object which is may held by some threads. It's kinda memory management thing. @AlanStokes

Comment: Don't do that. If there are threads waiting to use an object then you mustn't delete it. `shared_ptr` is your friend in this situation.

Comment: I tried, even `shared_ptr` must be managed thread-safe, and I had a situation where a thread checked there is no any dependency on `shared_ptr` then deleted the object, where just after `mutex` got released, another thread attempted to acquire the `mutex` while it has been deleted. I have posted something like this question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734697/removing-a-not-ready-object-at-runtime-cpp @AlanStokes thank you dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st question: Count them up, before letting them run into the lock. Count them down after having left the locked state.

2nd question: Look at `pthread_mutex_trylock()` Depending on its result (`EBUSY` or not) continue with `foo()` or call `bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard pthreads way to get the count of waiting threads.

As to the second question, you could use [`pthread_mutex_trylock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock).