# removing a not-ready object at runtime cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading

considering following class

```
class test{
private: long long id;
//some field....
public: test(){};
void do_something(){
//some huge operations....
}
void do_something_else(void* arg){
//yet another huge work load.....
}
}
///////////////////////////
void* _thread(void* _ins){
test* ins=(test*)_ins;
//some work
if(<<some condition>>){delete ins;}//not thread safe, std::auto_ptr doesn't help anymore
}
///////////////////////////
int main(){
test *ins=new test();
//pass the ins to 10 thread.
}
```

consider there are 10 threads using a shared object, when ever one of a thread delete the object, program exit.
Questions:
how can I get any error/exception at runtime when object gets deleted? `try-catch` didn't help. any solution?!
is there any thread-safe and consistence way to count the current thread using this object?
is there any event-based solution to fire an event when object is ready for purging?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use C++11 shared pointers (they have a reference count for shared instances): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Be sure to synchronize the check for that count in your threads (e.g. use a mutex or something similar)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't have global names with leading underscores, as those are reserved by the specification.

Comment: @DavidKernin thanks dude, either `std::shared_ptr` doesn't help. because as you mentioned I have to count the thread safe. but this is not safe at all. because two threads would change the value at a time(one increase/one decrease), and if first one goes first, it will delete the object which causes error for second thread.

Comment: Use std::shared_ptr, which is thread safe. In general, you'll want to have critical sections in your multi-threaded code to protect shared objects. Look up std::mutex.

Comment: shared_ptr + mutex is the way to go then, read again my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11's [shared_ptrs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) use **atomic increments/decrements** of a reference count value.

The standard **guarantees only one thread will call the delete operator on a shared object**.

What you need to make sure is that your critical section is synchronized, that is: **the shared object isn't freed if a thread is still using it**. You can use [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for that (a semaphore can be implemented with a mutex and a condition variable, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793662/1938163)